# dir function is changing the file path name of ".docx" files

Tags: r

I am making a list of all the files in a folder by using

```
dir(folderName, recursive = TRUE, all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
```

The resulting file paths are MOSTLY fine, but some of them (all of them are ".docx" files) are being changed. The name of the files are being changed from "AWordFile.docx" to  "~$ordFile.docx"

Also, it doesn't seem to do this to ALL of the ".docx" files, but only some of them.

I know that the file name is not being simply appended because I am comparing the two files with the file.size function:

```
> shortName2 <- "T:/AWordFile.docx"
> shortName <- "T:/~$ordFile.docx"
> file.size(shortName)
[1] 162
> file.size(shortName2)
[1] 40948
```

For some reason, every file that this happens to has the same file size.

Comment: Well, whenever I run file.size, it gives the incorrect size. If I use the FULL file path name it gives the correct size

Comment: Then I'm not sure.  I'll be interested to see the answer

Comment: for some reason, every file that this happens to says has file.size() of 162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~$ordFile.docx` is a temporary file created by Word to indicate the actual document `AWordFile.docx` is open. Close Word and try it again. Or if Word is already closed, just delete it -- sometimes it gets left behind if Word doesn't close properly.

The same applies to other Office apps, thus you may find `~$filename.pptx`, `~$filename.xlsx` etc lying around your hard disk.

Comment: What a pain in the @$$.. I am running this on a shared drive at my work and cannot just go and close all of these files. there are over 60 of them!  This makes sense though since all the files are the same size. After I verify that this works, I will accept. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @panterasBox Just remove these files from your list: `grep("^\\~\\$", dir(), invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)`

Comment: That may work.. sorry for asking you to hold my hand, but I actually have a list of vectors containing the file paths. I need to exclude all the list members that have these soo I need something like lapply(myList, function(i) grep("^\\~\\$", i, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)). How do I do that?

Comment: @panterasBox yep, that's what you'd do with a list of filenames.

Comment: Not working... But you answered my question. Thank you. I will figure this out.

Comment: I removed the "^" from grep and it worked. again, THANKS